# Printing lines from file using python returning value in column, not by row

Tags: python

I must have forgotten basic python since I cannot seem to print out lines by actual lines after splitting them so that each line as its elements in a list.

For example:

```
for lines in open(testfile):
     print(lines.split())
```

Outputs (note this is not a list of lists):

```
 ["The", "apple", "banana", "check"]
 ["Two", "apples", "three", "checks", "testest"]
 ["This", "is", "a", "test", "file"]
```

So if I want to print the very first line by itself I change the code to:

```
for lines in open(testfile):
     print(lines.split()[0])
```

But I get the first element in each line list:

```
 "The"
 "Two"
 "This"
```

But I expected:

```
["The", "apple", "banana", "check"]
```

I know this is syntax error and I have looked it up but I keep getting the first element only. Sorry this is so basic, but it's been a while since I've had to do something simple like this!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is going to look at each line in turn, so when you `print(lines.split()[0])`, you are doing that for a *single* line at a time. What you could do is put all of the split-up lines in a list of their own and then look at the first element in *that* list:

```
all_lines = []  # empty list
for line in open(testfile):
     all_lines.append(line.split())
all_lines[0]
# ["The", "apple", "banana", "check"]
```

As an aside, it's better to use the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) when opening files:

```
all_lines = []
with open(testfile) as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        all_lines.append(line.split())
```

The advantage here is that it creates a [context](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) in which the file operations run, and automatically handles things like closing the file.

Finally, if all you care about is the first line of the file, you can do:

```
with open(testfile) as a_file:
    first_line = a_file.readline().split()  # grab just the first line
first_line
# ["The", "apple", "banana", "check"]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I also need some advice on assigning variables to each item in each list. For example, "The"=var1, "apple"=var2, etc. I keep getting errors of "too many values to unpack".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `break` right after printing the first line:

```
for lines in open(testfile):
     print(lines.split())
     break
```

This will print only the first line

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Remember that control flow when you use [break] in more complex loops can yield unexpected results. Worth referring to the following for a refresher [Python - Control Flow](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html)